# How to make long sql sentence look beautiful in PHP(or other language)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-formatting

This is an example; For looking comfortable I fill some tab and line feed in it; I'm looking for some better ways except using '.' to link them.

```
$str_sql = "SELECT 
          sc.`id` AS 'payment_id',
          sc.`order_id` AS 'order_id',
          od.`partner_id` AS 'partner_id',
          pt.`partner_name` AS 'partner_name',
          od.`term` AS 'order_terms',
          od.`has_pay` AS 'paid_terms',
          sc.`sort_order` AS 'current_term',
          FROM_UNIXTIME(sc.`repayment_time`) AS 'payment_time',
          FROM_UNIXTIME(sc.`receive_time`) AS 'pay_time',
          sc.`order_price` AS 'term_price',
          od.`add_time` AS 'order_time',
          sc.`status` AS 'status',
          od.`order_price` AS 'order_price',
          usr.`user_name` AS 'user_name',
          usr.`id` AS 'user_id',
          usr.`user_cell` AS 'user_cellphone',
          IF(sc.`status` IN (0,3), 1 , 0 ) AS 'overdue',

        FROM 
          mayidev.`lzh_order_payment_schedule` sc 
          JOIN lzh_order od 
            ON sc.`order_id` = od.`id` 
          JOIN lzh_partners pt 
            ON od.`partner_id` = pt.`id` 
          JOIN lzh_order_user usr 
            ON od.id = usr.order_id 
          JOIN lzh_partner_overdue_interest po 
            ON po.`partner_id` = pt.id 
        WHERE sc.`repayment_time` < 1477441800
        AND sc.`receive_time` = 0
          AND sc.`status` != 1
          AND od.`status` = 4 ;";
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Are you asking about tools that will format it automatically? Requests for third-party software are off-topic here.

Comment: MySQL will ignore tabs and newlines so I don't see the issue with what you've got.

Comment: I'm not looking for some third-part tools for beautifying. In fact I'm afraid tabs and newlines will have a bad effects; I just hope my code can be compatible with more db if they were sensitive to tabs or newlines; Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make long SQL sentence look beautiful in PHP is to separate SQL code from PHP code. And the best way to do that is create `view`s and `stored procedure`s in SQL to get the data. You don't really need all this `JOIN`s logic in PHP. It is best stored on the SQL server to keep the code maintainable.

And on PHP side you can just `SELECT * FROM view` or `CALL procedure()`.